# Simple shell script doesn't work like command line?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a script that contains this

`screen -S demo -d -m` which should start a new screen session named demo and detach it.
Putting `screen -S demo -d -m` in the command line works.

If I put it in a file named boot.sh, and run it `./boot.sh` I get

`Error: Unknown option m`

Why does this work in the command line but not as a shell script?

Comment: What happens if you do: `. ./boot.sh`?

Comment: Could you exhibit a complete script that fails. If the one you are actually using is more than a few lines long, prepare a minimal version.

Comment: @dmckee What I have above is the entire script, its just the one screen command

Comment: @Kevin: Not even a shebang (`#! /bin/sh` or similar)?

Comment: @dmckee nope, I thought .sh files didn't need them?

Comment: @KevinDuke: They don't (this may be system-specific), but it is a good idea to include them.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce with the information you've given. "screen -S demo -d -m" behaves the same either on the command line or as the sole line in an executable script (without a shebang line). (Ubuntu 10.04, screen 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06)

Comment: Works fine here, shebang or not.

Comment: Just a guess here, but make sure there are no Ctrl-M chars at the end of your command-script by doing `cat -vet myScreenLaucher.sh`. It you see ^M at the end of the line, you are saving file in Windows file mode. You'll have to find the option in your editor to use Unix line endings. Good luck.

Comment: Use dos2unix utility to remove any unwanted character included by windows .. and run the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file was transferred from windows and had ctrl-M characters.

Answer (score 1):

Running "screen" on my Linux machine, a bad option (Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06) gives the error,

```
Error: Unknown option -z"
```

while your description includes no dash before the offending option.  I'd check that the characters in your script file are what you expect them to be.  There are many characters that look like a dash but which are not.

```
cat -v boot.sh
```

may show something interesting as it'll show codes for non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a little like the "*make sure your printer is plugged in*" kind of help, but anyway:

have you tried to check if the `screen` you're invoking from the script is the same as the one invoked from the command line ?

I'm thinking you may change the `PATH` variable inside your script somewhere and perhaps `screen` from the script would be something else (a different version, perhaps ?).